# Enterprise Java Beans video tutorials

Tags: asp.net, winforms, ejb, enterprise

Are there video tutorials for Enterprise Java Beans with the same caliber as asp.net and windowsclient.net Learn section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google 'EJB video'... a few to get you started

- [EJB Tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xf_cXJFYlmY)
- [EJB3 and Web Services](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5rwovAl_VNc)
- [EJB3 and Web Services II](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jA4eKtIdUPQ)
- [Java Persistence and EJB3](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/ejb-3)

Not sure what the quality of the resources you mentioned is - this stuff seems usable to me